# Creating module with autocomplete and accepting multiple values in textfield

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am creating my own form in my module using the Form API.

How do I enter multiple values in the below textfield and have it autocompleted, and suggested (separated by commas, for example)?

Right now it takes whatever is in the textfield box as one single big string.

```
$form['keywords'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Keywords'),
  '#size' => '40',
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#autocomplete_path' => 'papers_pub_search/keywords_autocomplete'
);

function _autosearch($string) {
  $query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE :name";
  $result = db_query($query, array(':name'=> '%' . db_like($string) . '%'));
  foreach($result as $row) {
    $match[$row->name] = check_plain($row->name);
  }
  drupal_json_output($match);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
function _autosearch($string) {
  $matches = array();

  if ($string) {
    $items = array_map('trim', explode(',', $string));
    $last_item = array_pop($items);
    $prefix = implode(', ', $items);

    $result = db_select('users')->fields('users', array('name'))->condition('name', '%' . db_like($last_item) . '%', 'LIKE')->range(0, 10)->execute();
    foreach ($result as $user) {
      $value = !empty($prefix) ? $prefix . ', ' . $user->name : $user->name;
      $matches[$value] = check_plain($value);
    }
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

This is the result.

[image: one username]

[image: two usernames]

[image: three usernames]

If you want to avoid a username can be used more than once, then you can use the following code.

```
function _autosearch($string = '') {
  $matches = array();

  if ($string) {
    $items = array_map('trim', explode(',', $string));
    $last_item = array_pop($items);
    $prefix = implode(', ', $items);

    $result = db_select('users')->fields('users', array('name'))->condition('name', '%' . db_like($last_item) . '%', 'LIKE')->range(0, 10)->execute();
    foreach ($result as $user) {
      if (!in_array($user->name, $items)) {
        $value = !empty($prefix) ? $prefix . ', ' . $user->name : $user->name;
        $matches[$value] = check_plain($value);
      }
    }
  }

  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

[image: usernames are not repeated]

Comment: This is a perfect example!  Worked well.  The one difference was that I used db_query() instead of your db_select().  Seems to make no difference.

Comment: Also, instead of array_map(), I used drupal_explode_tags().  It seems to give more flexibility on how keywords are separated.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_explode_tags/7

Comment: Here is d6 module which uses similar code provided by kiamlaluno https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_users_autocomplete

Comment: Thumbs up for the answer, Is there any module/solution for Drupal 8?