# multiple keyword match with db_like

Tags: database

I am using db_select for database query, following code works fine when $keyword is any string

```
 $result = db_select('my_table', 'mt')
        ->fields('mt')
        ->condition('my_column', '%' . db_like($keyword) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAllKeyed();
```

How can I make the same query working when $keyword is suppose to be an array of strings like ("del","mum") ,if my_column is location column so query will return me places like Delhi, Mumbai.

Comment: refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51089/creating-module-with-autocomplete-and-accepting-multiple-values-in-textfield for a similar example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build your query while looping through each keyword and adding this as an OR condition.

```
$db_or = db_or();
$query = db_select('my_table', 'mt');
$query->fields('mt');

foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $db_or->condition('my_column', '%' . db_like($keyword) . '%', 'LIKE');
}

$query->condition($db_or);
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();
```

Comment: Thanks!
syntax error at
$db_or->condition('my_column', '%' . db_like($keyword) . '%', 'LIKE'));
extra ')' at the end.